# How many Different (Ordered) arrangements of these characters are there, Assuming that the password is Case Sensitive and Repetition is NOT allowed?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There is a password that contains exactly 6 characters consisting of: 3 Digits, 2 Letters and 1 Special characters

Assuming there is only 7 special characters, how many different ordered arrangements of these characters are there (If password is case sensitive and Repetition is not allowed)

Is my solution correct?: 10 . 9 . 8 . 52 . 51 . 7 = 13 66 080 combinations

Or:

10p3 . 52p2 . 7p1 = 13 366 080 combinations

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

Your solution(s) (it is really the same solution; the first number misses a $3$) would work if you have to start with the 3 digits, followed by the 2 letters, and ends with the special character, but presumably you can mix those up in any order.

So, instead I would pick the 3 digits using the choose function (i.e. ${10 \choose 3}$), pick the 2 letters and the special symbol likewise, and then multiply by the number of permutations of those $6$ characters, i.e. $6!$. Thus, you get:

$${10 \choose 3} \cdot {52 \choose 2} \cdot {7 \choose 1} \cdot 6!$$

Comment: Does this account for non reptition of characters?

Comment: And wouldn't it be 10p3 . 52p2 . 7p1 . 6! since the password has to be ordered? e.g. the password CAT means that the characters must arrange to give CAT instead of TCA for example, which wouldn't count as the right password.

Comment: @Kenjor yes, it accounts for non-repetition. For example, ${10 \choose 3}$ is the number of groups of $3$ *different* digits. Indeed, by repeatedly using the choose function, you get all the different groups of characters. And by multiplying by $6!$ you get all the orders, i.e. Permutations. If you use $10p3$, you are already ordering/permuting, so multiplying by $6!$ will give you too many.

Comment: so by not multiplying by 6! you will just get the total combinations without order?

Comment: @Kenjor Correct!

Comment: so therefore could you say that 10p3 x 52p2 x 7p1 is equal to the ordered combinations?

Comment: @Kenjor No, because now you are just ordering the digits among each other, and same for the letters. That was my first comment: this would be the number of possibilities if the digits are in a fixed spot (say, the first three positions are digits), and same for the letters. But, you should be able to mix up the digits with the letters.